# How to fix bad blocks on SSD

Tags: ssd, bad-blocks

I've got 14 bad sectors on my Kingston HyperX SSD. Although any benchmark shows that SMART for this drive is good or 100% on CrystalDiskInfo. Is there any way to erase them? I've tried Vitoria with remap and erase options, but with no effect.

Comment: If you simply marked them a bad block?

Comment: Do you mean leave it as is?

Comment: Yes. Don't reformat them in the future, or make a badblock scan after that, that is all.

Comment: It can cause BSOD's or unexpected hangs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have tried software with "remap" option it may well be the bad blocks already has been remapped. 
They still get **shown** though, so that you get aware of the problem.

Then the only concern you should have is: does the bad block count **increase**?

If the count starts to increase - or you see IO failures - you may have an imminent disk failure to handle
(i.e. copy data over to a new disk, scrap this one).

Comment: I've already done with this. But I'm disturbed with one thing: bad blocks could be the root cause of BSOD's or unexpected system hangs? RAM diagnostic tool showed that it's okay.

Comment: `bad blocks could be the root cause of BSOD's or unexpected system hangs?` - if they **have been mapped out**, NO. But also note that if a **NEW** bad block appears in a vital spot on the disk, that **could** create a situation that related software cannot handle gracefully -> effect: `BSOD` to `nothing`.